# Find the Distribution that corresponds to the given MGF

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, moment-problem

I am working on a problem and am a little bit confused.

I need to find the distribution that corresponds to the MGF:

$2e^t\over3-e^t$

Do we need to separate this into something like:

2e$^t$ and $1\over3-e^t$

It seems like we might be able to separate this into X ~ Exp() or Poi()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MGF of a Poisson r.v. features a *double* exponential, and that of an exponential r.v. is a rational function (*no* exponential), so it looks unlikely at first glance these two would be candidates (also, unclear what you mean by "separate" here.)

However, eyeballing [the Wikipedia table showing a list of standard MGFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples), you can spot one that looks quite similar, that of the geometric distribution. Namely, if $X$ follows a Geometric distribution with parameter $p$, then the MGF of X is 
$$
M_x(t) = \frac{p e^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}, \quad t < \log\frac{1}{1-p} \tag{1}
$$
So let's see. What you have is
$$
M_X(t) = \frac{2e^t}{3-e^t} = \frac{\frac{2}{3}e^t}{1-\frac{1}{3}e^t}
= \frac{\frac{2}{3}e^t}{1-\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)e^t} \tag{2}
$$
which should allow you to conclude.

Comment: Thank you this clears a lot of things up.

Comment: @Ethan You're welcome!